# Issues with code modifying file structure when deploying

Tags: node.js, express, deployment

There is a site that contains data I want to parse through in my application. The JSON file is in a tar.gz. My code issues a request to that site, downloads the tar.gz file, extracts the JSON and then parses the information.

This is how the code looks so far but I have not added it into my backend yet.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const rp = require("request-promise");
const tar = require("tar");

(async function main() {
  try {
    const url = "https://statics.koreanbuilds.net/bulk/latest.tar.gz";
    const arcName = "latest.tar.gz";
    const response = await rp.get({ uri: url, encoding: null });
    fs.writeFileSync(arcName, response, { encoding: null });
    tar.x({ file: arcName, cwd: ".", sync: true });
    let text = fs.readFileSync("latest1.json");
    let fullText = JSON.parse(text);
    let championsObj = {};

    // Following logic that parses the json file
    .......

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

I plan on storing my parsed JSON object into MongoDB. I also want to perform the above operation and update the JSON and tar.gz file every 24 hours.

I am worried that these operations have many consequences when deploying this project. This is my first time deploying a Full stack application and I am almost positive that having code that messes with the file structure of the overall project will cause some issues. But I just don't know what exactly I should be worried about and how to tackle it. I believe that there will be a problem with CORS but I am more worried about the application actually working and updating correctly. The entire application is being made with the MERN stack.

Comment: Where do you plan on deploying?

Comment: @MaximOrlov I am deploying step by step to heroku. So far no issues but haven't tested it this specific code on it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deploy your code on a VPS, saving and reading from the filesystem is completely fine. When you deploy to PaaS like Heroku, you have to keep in mind that the [filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) which means that you get a fresh new copy on each deploy. Files that are not part of the version control will disappear after a release. You can't rely on the filesystem for storage and you have to use an external service to store images/files (e.g.: AWS S3).

Having said that, your code will work on Heroku because you're saving and reading from the file right away. One thing I'd do is add a date/timestamp to the downloaded file name so you don't get an error on the second run when a file with that name already exists. You could also research the possibility of extracting the archive in memory so you don't have to use the filesystem at all.

Other than that you shouldn't be worried. CORS is not relevant in this context.